# Prove that $f$ is discontinuous only at the boundary

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

[image]

---

It seems obvious, but somehow I find it difficult to prove it in an arbitrary metric space. How can I proceed in this case? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

First choose a nonboundary point.  It will have a neighborhood either completely in $S$ or completely in the complement of $S$.

Second choose a boundary point.  Each neighborhood of this point will have points both in $S$ and in the complement of $S$